# Interact with child view while scrolling ScrollView

Tags: android, button, scrollview

I've got a `LinearLayout` nested within a `HorizontalScrollView` that contains buttons. While the user's finger is still on the screen, scrolling the scroll view, I want the buttons to remain interactive.

At the moment, what I'm seeing is that the scroll view intercepts all touch events and the buttons can't be interacted with as long as the user is scrolling the view. Is there a way to allow single taps to pass through while scrolling is in progress?

Answer (score 0):

You will almost certainly need to override HorizontalScrollView with your own implementation (call it, say, com.appstruments.AppstrumentsHorizontalScrollView).

I would start off by seeing if you can override [onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) or [onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) so that it always returns false, which (hopefully) causes the touch events to be passed to the child views (i.e. your buttons).

Failing that, you might be able to pass the MotionEvents to the child views yourself in one of these functions.

Comment: Tried both of those options so far - and stopped myself once I realized that the events I needed to pass to the child views were not being intercepted in the first place by the handler. Will try that again and report back, though.